# How to copy o/p from cmd.exe and append it to a document only if it does not equal a particular value? in .VBS

Tags: shell, vbscript

I am really new to .vbs and am not sure how to build this out.

I am running a short script that runs a command in cmd.exe and copies/appends the output to a log file.

I would like to only append the o/p to the log file if the value does not match string"". How do I set this up? any help is much appreciated. I apologise if this question is off topic.

```
    Dim oShell
    Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
    oShell.run "cmd.exe /C cd " & str & ">>  log.txt"
    Set oShell = Nothing
```

The pseudo code for the if/else logic is shown below

```
if (o/p string = "A")
 action: do not do anything and end script
else
 copy string and append to file log.txt
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into the command `find`?
It allows you to do that without using VBScript

- `dir | find "string_to_find" >> logfile.txt` : copy only the text that matches
- `dir | find /I "string_to_avoid" >>logfile.txt` : same as above but case insensitive
- `dir | find /v "string_to_avoid" >> logfile.txt` : copy all strings that do not match

For more help on `find` type `find /?` in a command line.